# In Excel, how do I use INDIRECT to point to a cell that contains a sheet name for specific case

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to get `INDIRECT` to work to replace the Transactions2 sheet with a sheet name in A1 using the following formula:

`=IF(AND(Transactions2!$K2>=Periods!$B$3, Transactions2!$K2<=Periods!$C$3),Transactions2!$L2,"")`

Periods is OK as is without `INDIRECT` as I'm checking the date in Transactions2!$K2 against dates in Periods sheet to determine if it falls within a date range. If in the range, I grab the dollar amount in L2 else I leave it blank.

I tried

`=IF(AND(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!"&$K2>=Periods!$B$3), INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!"&$K2<=Periods!$C$3),INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!"&$L2,"")`

and

`=IF(AND(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!$K2>=Periods!$B$3"), INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!&$K2<=Periods!$C$3"),INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!"&$L2,"")`

and both give #REF errors

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, just needs a small tweak:

```
=IF(AND(INDIRECT(A1 & "!$K2")>=Periods!$B$3, INDIRECT(A1 & "!$K2")<=Periods!$C$3),INDIRECT(A1 & "!$L2"),"")
```

*(The single quotes are only needed if the sheet name contains a space.)*

Comment: Thanks for the help!! That worked although, I lose the ability to auto-increment the row for '$K2' when copy/pasting the formula. I assume this is a limitation of 'INDIRECT'

Answer (score 1):

If I recall, you need toinclude the `K2`within the quotes:

```
=IF(AND(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!$K2">=Periods!$B$3), INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!$K2"<=Periods!$C$3),INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!$L2","")
```